# Why any HTTP request did not send while using Transfer-Encoding header?

Tags: http, header

This is HTTP request with POST method and Content-Length header:

```
POST /pg3.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: pg3_cookie=123456

user=mehran
```

This is HTTP request with POST method and Transfer-Encoding header:

```
POST /pg3.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.10.10.8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: pg3_cookie=123456

11
user=mehran
0
```

When using WireShark on the server-side, there is **no HTTP request** for the second sample (HTTP request with Transfer-Encoding header) and **instead there's TCP push packet** which contains HTTP request.

Why this is happened??

Here is the WireShark for both request:

[WireShark-HTTP-Content-Length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuo2b.jpg)

[WireShark-HTTP-Transfer-Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZH42.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Chunked encoding transmission use **hexadecimal** format to indicate the size of the chunks.

`11` in hexadecimal means `17` in decimal (`11` would be `b`).

here with a chunk size of 17 bytes your chunk is fully transmitted but you lack the end-of-chunk marker (\r\n0\r\n\r\n) because it was eaten in the 1st chunk:

```
u s e r = m e h r a n \r \n
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 a b c d  e
0 \r \n
f 10 11
\r \n
12 13
```

So it's either:

```
b\r\n
user=mehran\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

or

```
11\r\n
user=mehran\r\n
0\r\n
0\r\n
\r\n
```

Comment: You're right. I had a mistake there. I'll appreciate you also help me with the question itself too. Why using Transfer-Encoding in HTTP request, cause making a TCP Push packet instead of HTTP?

Comment: I think yhis is just a 'visual' artefact, as it's invalid HTTP the gui does not replace the TCP elements with the tcp-protol top layer label